# How can I debug firewall settings in centos?

Tags: centos, ssh, firewall, port

I'm trying to change my default ssh port to 21212 but something seems to be blocking the new port.

After editing the ssh config and restarting the service, I can see from `netstat -l` that the sshd is now listening to the new port.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21212           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:21212              [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

And systemctl shows that firewalld is inactive.

```
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
   Docs: man:firewalld(1)
```

And also, `sestatus` shows that SELinux is disabled.

```
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

But when I try to connect through the new port, my connection times out.

How am I supposed to debug/analyze this problem?

+ I can connect to my another server that uses the same hosting company/port(21212)

ouput for `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Output of tcpdump

```
19:59:47.470133 IP @@@.@@@.@@@.@@@.63719 > ###.###.###.###.21212: Flags [SEW], seq 3386796907, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 340882351 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:59:48.473671 IP @@@.@@@.@@@.@@@.63719 > ###.###.###.###.21212: Flags [S], seq 3386796907, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 340883351 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:59:49.479787 IP @@@.@@@.@@@.@@@.63719 > ###.###.###.###.21212: Flags [S], seq 3386796907, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 340884351 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:59:50.482778 IP @@@.@@@.@@@.@@@.63719 > ###.###.###.###.21212: Flags [S], seq 3386796907, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 340885351 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:59:51.485576 IP @@@.@@@.@@@.@@@.63719 > ###.###.###.###.21212: Flags [S], seq 3386796907, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 340886351 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:59:52.489498 IP @@@.@@@.@@@.@@@.63719 > ###.###.###.###.21212: Flags [S], seq 3386796907, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 340887351 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:59:54.504307 IP @@@.@@@.@@@.@@@.63719 > ###.###.###.###.21212: Flags [S], seq 3386796907, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 340889352 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:59:58.523589 IP @@@.@@@.@@@.@@@.63719 > ###.###.###.###.21212: Flags [S], seq 3386796907, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 340893352 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
20:00:06.581364 IP @@@.@@@.@@@.@@@.63719 > ###.###.###.###.21212: Flags [S], seq 3386796907, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 340901352 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
20:00:22.739680 IP @@@.@@@.@@@.@@@.63719 > ###.###.###.###.21212: Flags [S], seq 3386796907, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 340917352 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

Comment: What CentOS you use? Maybe there is enables iptables? Just show output for `iptables-save` or `iptables -L`.

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev, I'm on CentOS7 and added the output at the end of the question

Answer (score 1):

Start `tcpdump` and connect to the host on the port in question.

If something on your VM is blocking the traffic, tcpdump will still show `SYN` packets. If there's no traffic at all, another box along the way might drop your traffic. Plus, verify that your network config is ok.

Comment: This maybe a little off topic but as I do not have physical access to the server, changing the port number and doing these tests is kind of scary because if anything happens(pc reboot/shell crash) and I lose current shell connection then I have no way to connect back. Is there anything else other than the actual sshd that I can run the test against?

Comment: Use netcat it has a listen mode.

Comment: Thanks @fuero. So I ran `netcat` in listening mode on the server and and connected to the server also using `netcat` from my pc. And I captured the packet using `tcpdump` from my pc. As you can see from the output I added to the question, somehow I only see S flags. And when I try `tcpdump` on the server side, I get nothing. Does it mean my pc is trying to connect to the server but it cannot reach the server using the port? Is there a way to find out at which point of the route the traffic is blocked?